# Email users of Wordpress Blog when a new blog post is created

Tags: email, wordpress

I searched for plugin which will send automatic post email to subscribers when I post on my Wordpress blog but I had no luck finding this kind of plugin.

Does any one know any plugin which can do this thing?

Answer (score 4):

[Subscribe2](https://wordpress.org/plugins/subscribe2/) does what you are looking for.

> Subscribe2 provides a comprehensive subscription management and email
>   notification system for WordPress blogs that sends email notifications
>   to a list of subscribers when you publish new content to your blog.
>
> Email Notifications can be sent on a per-post basis or periodically in
>   a Digest email. Additionally, certain categories can be excluded from
>   inclusion in the notification and posts can be excluded on an
>   individual basis by setting a custom field.
>
> The plugin also handles subscription requests allowing users to
>   publicly subscribe (Public Subscribers) by submitting their email
>   address in an easy to use form or to register with your blog
>   (Registered Users) which enables greater flexibility over the email
>   content for per-post notifications for the subscriber. Admins are
>   given control over the presentation of the email notifications, can
>   bulk manage subscriptions for users and manually send email notices to
>   subscribers.

Screenshot of the plugin interface

[image]

<sup>Credits: [Subscribe2 Wordpress Plugins Page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/subscribe2/screenshots/)</sup>